# Saving object inside another object - Room Android

Tags: android, android-room

I have a object saved in my room database, and I need to add one more object within it.

```
@Entity
data class GameProfileEntity(
        @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
        val level: String,
        val monthlyGoalsEntity: MonthlyGoalsEntity)
```

And I'm don't know how to put this on room migration. 
This is my migration method:

```
        execSQL("CREATE TABLE GameProfileEntity_backup(id INTEGER NOT NULL, level TEXT NOT NULL, monthlyGoals_goalsEntity TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, synced INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY (id));")
        execSQL("INSERT INTO GameProfileEntity_backup (id, level) SELECT id, level FROM GameProfileEntity")
        execSQL("DROP TABLE GameProfileEntity")
        execSQL("ALTER TABLE GameProfileEntity_backup RENAME TO GameProfileEntity")
```

I don't have sql expertise, only some crud stuffs, should I create a table for `MonthlyGoalsEntity` and use join to save inside `GameProfileEntity`?